# How can I order views Attachments in views page

Tags: 7, views

I have created to views attachments and placed them after my views page. 
But the issue is the order of the attachments is in reverse.
How can I add weight to them?

Answer (score 7):

Actually Drupal have re-order display, but I think it is for admin page only.

I also got same problems as you, but finally I found a way.

1) Click to ADVANCE.
[image]

2) Click to the machine name and edit it by ABC order.

Hope it will help.